# Which database table is better?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just want some advice, when creating a "Question" Table in the database, do I need store in the question number for each question or is this not needed as each question will have its own unique Id thanks to auto increment and that when students take the exam, the questions are going to appear in random order for each student so they can't copy answers.

In other words should the Question table be like this (Example 1):

```
    QuestionId (int 11) auto increment PK  //unique identifier for each question
    QuestionNo (int 3) //the question number
    QuestionContent (varchar 800) //the question itself
AnswerId (int 11) //Foreign key to AnswerId in Answer Table
```

Or should it be like this (example 2):

```
    QuestionId (int 11) auto increment PK  //unique identifier for each question
    QuestionContent (varchar 800) //the question itself
AnswerId (int 11) //Foreign key to AnswerId in Answer Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. The auto-increment PK field means that each question will have a unique ID number. The only reason you'd need to provide another question number field is if you need to be able to find questions according to some other numbering system that's already determined, or if the question number has some other significance.

Comment: +1. I also don't understand the need for two [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

Answer (score 1):

I would make `QuestionNo` a field of a table that would join a test and a question. For example, I would have a `Question_on_Test` which would contain that field because it is only pertinent for a specific test revision and not pertinent on the question itself.

Comment: Couldn't question_on_test just as easily reference the question by its primary key, though? Why would you need a separate question number field for that?

Comment: Well it depends if the order is important. Of course, it would still *reference* the question by its PK, but keeping track of the question number on that specific test could be relevant. That's a case of knowing the business rules.

Answer (score 0):

In your second design, if you remove a question from the database (for whatever reason) you will lose that question's ID number. That's something which may or may not be critical to your design.

Comment: Is that not true in the first design as well?

Comment: Yes. I didn't pay attention there. You would obviously lose the pk value in the first design as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to have an AnswerID in the question table.  This is assuming there could be several answers to one question (a one-to-many relationship).  There is usually one right answer and several wrong answers.

If there is a just one answer per question, it doesn't need to be in a separate table.

Edit:  And, since the questions can be randomly ordered, a question number is meaningless.

I think the Answer table should be:

```
int AnswerID  (unique ID)
char AnswerChar (A, B, C, D, E)
int QuestionID (parent Question ID)
bool IsCorrect
text AnswerText
```

Comment: There could be multiple answers to a question for Example, one question could have answer A B E, next question answer could be E, next question answer could be A D F H, next question answer True .... But I put the AnswerId in Question Table because lets say for one question the AnswerId is 23, and in the `Answer` Table we find out AnswerId 23 contains the Answer A D F H, then that is the answer for that question, do you think that is fine?